# Sql Query Difficult with sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Customers ( id | name )`, with id and name of fornitori,
and another table `Money (id | idcustomers | give | have )`.

`Give` and `have` are `int` field, with the money that the customer gave and the sum create the balance.

I would like to create a query that shows for each customer the name and the different 
of `SUM(GIVE) - SUM(HAVE)` where `money.idcustomers = customers.id`

Comment: Please give a query that you are struggling with, and then community can pick up from there.

Answer (score 1):

Just grouping by customer id should do the trick:

```
SELECT Customers.name, SUM(GIVE) - SUM(HAVE) total
FROM Customers
JOIN Money ON Money.idcustomers = Customers.id
GROUP BY Customers.id
```

SQL Fiddle demo;  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/339032/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.name, (SUM(M.give)-SUM(M.Have)) AS total
FROM Customors C, Money M
WHERE C.id = M.idcustomers
ORDER BY C.name
GROUP BY C.name
```